# What is the definition of subalgebra of given $R$-algebra $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be an ring.
> What is the definition of subalgebra of given $R$-algebra $A$?

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find definition.

My guess, $B⊆A$ is an $R$-subalgebra of $A$ if only if $B$ is subring of $A$ and has ring hom from $R$ ?

Refference (website, etc) is also appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's basically right, but the structure map $R \to B$ must be the same as the structure map $R \to A$ (in particular, $B$ must contain the image of the structure map $R \to A$).

Comment: Thank you ! Is this standard definition ? (I don't know the reason, but I couldn't find anywhere the definition of sub algebra.)

Comment: I don't think it's that difficult to find a definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subalgebra